# chrome extension custom hash fragment

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Lets say I have a chrome extension which watches which url the user is at, could this chrome extension look for a special delimiter in the url(like a hash fragment) to signal an action to take? Here's an example:

The user clicks the link

https://google.com#signaltoextension

The extension could then check the url for the #signaltoextension and take some action.

The problem with this approach is, what if the url already has a hash fragment on it?

could I do something like this?

https://google.com#preexistinghashfragment##signaltoextension

Basically, I'm looking for a proper delimiter that allows a user without the extension to follow the link without consequence, but if a user has the extension for it to take action.

**Here's my use case:**

A user with the extension is at the link:

```
https://google.com
```

He wants to associate some information with this link to share it with another user. Lets say, in the extension he associates the information "google rocks" with google.com, the extension sends this to the my server along with the user's username, lets say his username is linkguy. Then linkguy shares the link `https://google.com{delimiter}linkguy` with another user. The other user visits this link, the extension sees the delimiter, queries the server for google.com{delimiter}linkguy, then the extension displays "google rocks". If someone who does not have the extension clicks the link, it should simply follow the link without consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no. There can only be a single fragment identifier, and you will break the existing one.

Moreover, the fragment identifier is often processed by both the server (analytics tracking) and the client-side code, so passing a fragment identifier is not guaranteed to be "without consequence".

You can, in principle, try to catch such a "special" identifier with WebRequest and cut it out before the request is sent. But for people without the extension, that would break it.

Comment: is there any way for a user without the extension to use the link with the "special" identifier without consequence?

Comment: Definitely not. Maybe if you present your use case better, there's another solution.

Comment: I tried to present my use case better, i've updated my question.

Comment: Actually that's a great idea, if the user doesn't have the app, i can just redirect them to the proper link, if they do, I can redirect them and let the extension know via http.